# sed awk grep ? for find exact line number

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

here is an example of my `datafile.txt`

```
jones
dave
mike
dave
nathan
ben
james
jim
dave
dave
jones
bill
john
```

i am using grep to find string `dave` which is fine

```
grep "dave" datafile.txt >> duplicate.txt
```

i need to find which line # that string `dave` was found

first match `dave` is on line # `2`
next `dave` is on line # `4`
next `dave` is on line # `9`
next `dave` is on line # `10`

and `2nd` query to find the line count between the last occurrence

so first match is `0`
2nd match is after `2` lines
third match is after `5` lines
fourth match is after `1` line

so need to know the exact line number as well as the line number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple awk can do the work for you

```
$ awk '/dave/{print NR}' input
2
4
9
10
```

**What it does**

- `/dave/` matches `/dave/` on the line
- `{print NR}` prints the `NR`, line number.

And

```
$ awk '/dave/{print prev?NR-prev:0; prev=NR}' input
0
2
5
1
```

**What it does?**

- `prev` variable contains the previous line which matches the `/dave/`
- `prev?NR-prev:0` if `prev` is set, then print `NR-prev` else print `0`
- `prev=NR` sets the `prev` as the current `NR`